# ELK - X-Pack Custom realm

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-x-pack, xpack

I've developed a custom realm for my ELK cluster.

This module works well on a on node elasticsearch but when I install it on my production cluster, nothing works.

Elasticsearch starting logs : 
 - nothing special, everything seems to work and xpack module is loaded (generates a log in stdout)

Elasticsearch cluster diagnostic (custom seems to be disabled and not available) :

```
{
  "security" : {
    "available" : true,
    "enabled" : true,
    "realms" : {
      "file" : {
        "available" : true,
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "ldap" : {
        "available" : true,
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "native" : {
        "name" : [
          "realm2"
        ],
        "available" : true,
        "size" : [
          2
        ],
        "enabled" : true,
        "order" : [
          1
        ]
      },
      "custom" : {
        "available" : false,
        "enabled" : false
      },
...
}
```

Elasticsearch configuration :

```
cluster.name: "production-cluster-1"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.watcher.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: "-------------------"
network.publish_host: "----"

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

xpack.security:
  authc:
    realms:
      realm1:
        type: custom
        order: 0
      realm2:
        type: native
        order: 1
```

The native authentication works fine.

How can I troubleshoot this correctly ?  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by turning up the logging:

```
curl -u<user> -XPUT '<host>:<http-port>/_cluster/settings?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "transient": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc": "DEBUG"
  }
}
'
```

That will give you any authentication logs on debug. I think the right package for the native realm should be [`logger.org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.esnative`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/x-pack/plugin/security/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/security/authc/esnative) in case you want to limit it down just to that.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser,

I forgot to mention, I'm in version 5.6.3.

I activated DEBUG logs as you recommended but I only get this kind of logs :

[DEBUG][o.e.x.s.a.e.ReservedRealm] [J61LJrE] user [my_user] not found in cache for realm [reserved], proceeding with normal authentication
[DEBUG][o.e.x.s.a.e.NativeRealm  ] [J61LJrE] realm [realm2] authenticated user [my_user], with roles [[MY-ROLE]]

Comment: That only means that the user cannot be found. Either because it doesn't exist (typo in the username maybe) or because you cannot connect to the source of the user IMO.